# How can I custom format in excel to place periods (as separators) in an 18 digit entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, format

This is regarding 18-digit accounting codes that contain multiple periods, as separators. I would like to enter just the digits without typing in the periods. Example:

```
112233333444555556
```

would automatically format as

```
11.22.33333.444.55555.6
```

I have used this formula:

```
??"."??"."?????"."???"."?????"."?
```

which works except for the last digit always comes up as 0

How should this code be changed to accept any numeral as entered in the last space?

Comment: Excel cannot handle numbers with more than 15 digits and will replace any more digits with zeros. If you look closely you will see that the last three digits have been replaced by zeros, not just the last one. You will need to enter the value as text and put in the dots manually, or use VBA to manipulate the text.

Answer (score 2):

Here is VBA code that monitors column A and adds the dots when the text entry has 18 characters. Select the whole column and format is as Text, then you can type or paste the 18 digit code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim s As String
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Len(Target) = 18 Then
        s = Left(Target, 2) & "." & _
        Mid(Target, 3, 2) & "." & _
        Mid(Target, 5, 5) & "." & _
        Mid(Target, 10, 3) & "." & _
        Mid(Target, 13, 5) & "." & _
        Right(Target, 1)
        Target.Value = s
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @[teylyn](https://superuser.com/users/107753/teylyn), Excel follows the IEEE 754 specification for floating-point numbers and can only store 15 significant digits. The easiest, non-macro workaround is splitting the formula into two parts (the left most 15 digits and the right most remaining digits).

```
=TEXT(
   LEFT([input], 15), format_left
 ) & 
 TEXT(
   RIGHT([input], LEN([input]) - 15), format_right
 )
```

i.e.

`= TEXT(LEFT(A2,15),"00-00-00000-000-000") & TEXT(RIGHT(A2,3),"00-0")`

```
| Account number     | Account number (formatted) |
| ------------------ | -------------------------- |
| 112233333444555556 | 11-22-33333-444-55555-6    |
```